# Linux cluster shell for parallel matlab simulation

Tags: linux, matlab

I need to call a matlab function with different input arguments in Linux shell, I wrote my loop in the following form and it works:

```
set c=1 

while ( $c <= 5 ) 

#JOB='qsub -m abe -N Big_run - << EOJ matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop << M_PROG test ($c); M_PROG EOJ` 

@ c = $c + 1 

end
```

There are 2 problems, one is " mismatched `. "

The other one is how to pass input argument to matlab function?

Comment: How is it "working" if you have those 2 problems... You mean you just have the looping working, but not the command? More importantly, what shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, just use a matching apostrophe `'` instead of the grave tick `` ` ``:

```
#JOB='qsub -m abe -N Big_run - << EOJ matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop << M_PROG test ($c); M_PROG EOJ'
```

For your second problem, run it like this...

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "yourFunction(42)"
```

...where 42 is your input argument.

More information here: [Unix commandline start: passing arguments to m file](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231705-unix-commandline-start-passing-arguments-to-m-file?s_tid=answers_rc1-3_p3). A good example from near the end:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -r "input('A'),input('B'),input('C','s')"
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the following line to call matlab by qsub command, but i get the "Ambiguous input redirect." error, 
In other words, how can I run Matlab directly by means of qsub command?

set JOB=`qsub -m abe - << EOJ  matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop << M_PROG 'test($c);exit'  M_PROG EOJ`